# Bind image from external source

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, data-binding

I'm attempting to bind a background image from an external data source through Vue.js. This is what the code looks like:

```
<div class="image-box border"
            :style="{ background: `url(`+ item.image +`) no-repeat center` }" 
            style="width: 220px; height: 220px">
```

I've also tried this:

```
<div class="image-box border" 
            :style="{ 'backgroundImage': 'url(' + item.image + ')' }">
```

This is what the url reads like in the app with no error:

```
background-image: url("http://localhost:8080/assets/images/shoe-1.png");
```

Any help is appreciated!

Full code:

component -

```
<template>
    <div class="product-card-box border">
        <div class="image-box border"
                :style="{ background: `url(`+ item.image +`) no-repeat center` }" 
                style="width: 220px; height: 220px">
             <!-- :style="{ 'backgroundImage': 'url(' + item.image + ')' }"> -->

        </div>
        <div class="info-box border">
            <div class="color-info product-info bold">{{item.colors.length}} color</div>
            <div class="product-name">
                <div class="product-info bold">{{item.name}}</div>
                <div class="product-info sub-info">{{item.gender}}'s Shoe</div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-price">
                <div class="product-info sub-info">${{item.price}}</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

data -

```
const data = [
{
    name: 'SNKR 001',
    gender: 'Men',
    price: 100,
    sport: 'running',
    width: 'Wide',
    colors: ['black', 'white', 'green', 'pink'],
    sizes: [3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 12.5, 13, 14, 15],
    image: '../assets/images/shoe-1.png'
},
{
    name: 'SNKR 002',
    gender: 'Men',
    price: 100,
    sport: 'running',
    width: 'Wide',
    colors: ['black', 'white', 'green', 'pink'],
    sizes: [3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 12.5, 13, 14, 15],
    image: '../assets/images/shoe-1.png'
}
];
export default data;
```

Comment: In `data[]`, use `require(path)` like this `image: require('../assets/images/shoe-1.png')`.

Comment: @tony19 Thanks, that did the trick! Can you past this into an answer so I can choose it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `data[]`, use `require(path)` so that the path is correctly resolved in your template:

```
image: require('../assets/images/shoe-1.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider just having one `style` object. Also, does it have to be a background image? I'm sure you could accomplish the same thing with an `img` and a class and just making it `object-fit`.

```
<div id="app">
  <div :style="{ 
    width: '200px',
    height: '200px',
    'background-image': `url(${backgroundImage}`,
   }"/>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    backgroundImage: 'http://picsum.photos/g/1200/400?image=30',
  },
})
```

Check this fiddle for the `object-fit` solution https://jsfiddle.net/caseyjoneal/b5r8fvjq/73/

Comment: I like these ideas a lot - I’ll implement them in my next project.