# Incorrect URL path for images using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, vuejs2, template-strings

I'm new to **Vue.js** and I'm starting a new project that load images dynamically in some different ways.

That said I run it thru `npm run dev` and get those crashed image icons and the following  error in the console log:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/@/assets/images/myimage.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is a piece of my code that goes inside a loop and uses a function that returns an image path that goes inside an SVG:

```
container.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<image xlink:href="${setItem(i).filePath}" x="${x}" y="${y}" width="16" height="16"/>`)
```

I have some images that also loads with and without a function that returns its path but not inside a SVG:

```
<image src="${setItem(i).filePath}" alt="">
<image src="@/assets/images/myimage.svg" alt="">
```

As I said, **all images are broken**. Please what am I doing wrong?

P.S.: Feel free to suggest editing the title for a better comprehension of the issue.

Comment: where is your assets folder located? check this https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports

Comment: @Estradiaz /src/assets

Comment: i think instead @ use .

Comment: Where does `setItem(i).filePath` come from? On the place where it is generated, do you `import` it to get the correct url?

Comment: No `./assets...` nor `../assets...` work. The `setItem(i).filePath` is just a function with some conditions (based oh current time and other stuffs) that returns the path of the image. But the path should start with some kind of bind data (sorry, I don't know how to explain).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind image from external source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54993339/bind-image-from-external-source)

Comment: @ed1nh0 Use a computed property (e.g., named `imgSrc`) that returns `require('@/assets/images/myimage.svg')`, and bind the property: `<img :src="imgSrc">`.

Answer (score 0):

> Relative Path Imports
>
> When you reference a static asset using relative
>   path (must start with .) inside JavaScript, CSS or *.vue files, the
>   asset will be included into webpack's dependency graph. During this
>   compilation process, all asset URLs such as ,
>   background: url(...) and CSS @import are resolved as module
>   dependencies.

with this i think all you have to do is replace `@/...` with `./...`

[docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports)

Comment: this is weird - as those files are not in your public domain they have to be module loaded?  can you try: `new Vue({
  render: h => h('img', { attrs: { src: require('./assets/images/myimage.svg') } })
    
}).$mount("#app");`